# Are there 16 registers in x64?

Tags: 64-bit, x86-64, cpu, intel, cpu-registers

One the one hand I read that x64 cpus have 16 registers, I took a look at the list and a lot are missing like Eflags register, why is that?

why it is not counted into the total registers? it seems like a contradiction to me

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/x64-architecture

Answer (score 2):

It has 16 general purpose registers which can be the target of most instructions and used as address pointers and array indices. The flags register, program counter, floating point registers, 8 MMX registers and 16 SSE registers all require different sets of instructions to operate and can't be used as address pointers or array indices.

Comment: VSIB addressing mode is an exception when SSE register can be used for addressing, see https://euroassembler.eu/eatests/t5170.htm

Comment: @vitsoft: true, but only with AVX2 (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpgatherdd:vpgatherqd) or AVX-512 (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpgatherdd:vpgatherdq and scatter), not baseline for x86-64.  If I was going to nit-pick, I'd first point out segment, control, and debug registers, and maybe even MSRs (accessed with rd / [`wrmsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrmsr) with the MSR-number in a GP register) :P

Answer (score 2):

From the link you provided, there is an excerpt:

> x64 extends x86's 8 general-purpose registers to be 64-bit, and adds 8 new 64-bit registers.

As you can see, it isn't talking about all registers here, it's only talking about **general-purpose registers** (The list after this excerpt which I think you are talking about is also only showing general-purpose registers). As the name implies, these registers have no specific purpose and are mostly used to store temporary data or for addressing. Flags do not count as general-purpose registers. They each have a specific purpose and you can't access them directly. Instead, they are set through various instructions and are checked mostly in conditional instructions. Note, however, that the page does mention the flag registers, they just don't count them in the general-purpose registers:

> The instruction pointer, eip, and flags register have been extended to 64 bits (rip and rflags, respectively) as well.

Comment: You can read and write RFLAGS more or less directly with `pushf` and `popf`.  It's not general-purpose, though!  (Also note that GP just means address-or-data as opposed to an ISA like m68k that had a0..7 and d0..7, not "anything".  For example, you can't use RAX for SIMD instructions like `addps`; you need XMM registers for that.)

Comment: x86-64 also doubled the number of XMM vector regs to 16, but the number of MMX vectors is still 8, same as the number of x87 st0..7 registers.  And of course there are [debug](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-2) and [control](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1) regs, and segment regs.

Comment: @PeterCordes fixed the definition of general-purpose, thanks :)

Comment: @pet Plus an undocumented amount of machine-specific registers (some of which are ['interesting'](https://youtu.be/jmTwlEh8L7g), in a *very* bad way).